# Django OperationalError: "Error 'repetition-operator operand invalid' from the regexp"

Tags: python, regex, django

I have asked this question before and the answer led to this error that I am unable to solve.

I have an `Article` model that takes in articles from users. These articles can get *#hashtags* in them like we have in twitter. I have these hashtags converted to links that users can click to load all articles that have the clicked hashtags in them.

If have these articles saved in `Article` model:

```
1.  'For the love of learning: why do we give #Exam?'
2.  'Articles containing #Examination should not come up when exam is clicked'
3.  'This is just an #example post'
```

I tried using Django's `__icontains` filter

```
def hash_tags(request, hash_tag):
    hash_tag = '#' + hash_tag
    articles = Articles.objects.filter(content__icontains=hash_tag)
    articles = list(articles)
    return HttpResponse(articles)
```

but if user clicks on `#exam` the three articles are returned instead of the first one.

I can add space to *'#exam'* to become *'#exam '* and it will work out fine but I want to be able to do it with regex.

I have tried:

```
articles = Articles.objects.filter(content__iregex=r"{0}\b".format(hash_tag))
```

but I get empty response.

And this:

```
articles = Articles.objects.filter(content__iregex=r"(?i){0}\b".format(hash_tag))
```

returns **"Error 'repetition-operator operand invalid' from regexp"**

How do I do this correctly to have it work? I am using Django 1.6 and MySQL at backend.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL doesn't understand Perl regexp. You must read [MySQL regex](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html) and use `[[:>:]]`. The string `'\b'` in Python is a backspace.

For [regex in Python](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) must be used double backspace `'\\b'` or "raw" string prefixed with "r" `r'\b'`.

You should check safe characters in the hashtag. A bad user can otherwise construct a regex that would be analyzed forever (DOS attack).